# Extending the AbstractUser Model in Django

Tags: django, django-models

What are the attributes that are defined in the Django AbstractUser model?

I have extended the model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

Do I have to create my own fields for username, first name, last name, etc? Or are they already defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you can find these fields are already defined. 
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L288

However if you want user class without these fields look for AbstractBaseUser class
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py#L47

Answer (score 1):

Yes those fields (username, email, first_name, last_name, is_staff, is_active, date_joined) are already defined for the AbstractUser. You can view the fields in the django admin. [Check the source code here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py)